# how to pool MI confidence intervals of robust mixed model in r?

Tags: r, mixed-models, r-mice, robust

I can run the `rlmer` model with the object that results from `mice`, but when I try to pool the results a get the message `Error: No tidy method for objects of class rlmerMod`. Is there an alternative?

Below there is a reproducible example of my data and models:

```r
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
library(robustlmm)
library(mice)
library(miceadds)

dt <- data.table(id = rep(1:10, each=3), 
                 group = rep(1:2, each=15),
                 time = rep(1:3, 10),
                 sex = rep(sample(c("F","M"),10,replace=T), each=3),
                 x = rnorm(30),
                 y = rnorm(30))

setDT(dt)[id %in% sample(1:10,4) & time == 2, `:=` (x = NA, y = NA)][
          id %in% sample(1:10,4) & time == 3, `:=` (x = NA, y = NA)]
                        
# Multiple imputation -------------------------------------------------------------------

pm <- make.predictorMatrix(dt)
pm[,c('x','y')] <- 0
pm[c('x','y'), 'id'] <- -2
imp <- mice(dt, pred = pm, meth = "2l.pmm", seed = 1, m = 2, print = FALSE, maxit = 20)

# Modelling -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

m <- with(imp, rlmer(y ~ 1 + time * group + sex + (1 | id), REML=F))
pool.fit <- pool(m)

> pool.fit <- pool(m)
Error: No tidy method for objects of class rlmerMod
In addition: Warning message:
In get.dfcom(object, dfcom) : Infinite sample size assumed. # I don't get this warning using my real data
```

Thank you!

EDIT:

As commented by @BenBolker, `library(broom.mixed)` gets `pool.fit` to run without errors. Hovever, `summary(pool.fit,conf.int = TRUE)` returns the estimates, but `NaN` for degrees of freedom, p values and confidence intervals.

```
library(broom.mixed)

pool.fit <- pool(m)
summary(pool.fit,conf.int = TRUE)

         term    estimate std.error   statistic  df p.value 2.5 % 97.5 %
1 (Intercept) -1.31638288 1.2221584 -1.07709683 NaN     NaN   NaN    NaN
2        time  0.02819273 0.4734632  0.05954578 NaN     NaN   NaN    NaN
3       group  1.49581955 0.8776475  1.70435124 NaN     NaN   NaN    NaN
4        sexM -0.61383469 0.7137998 -0.85995356 NaN     NaN   NaN    NaN
5  time:group -0.25690287 0.3005254 -0.85484573 NaN     NaN   NaN    NaN
```

I don't know if another parameter is needed (eg., for defining the df method).

For now, I tried `tbl_regression(m)` but it didn't work either:

```
> tbl_regression(m)
pool_and_tidy_mice(): Tidying mice model with
`mice::pool(x) %>% mice::tidy(exponentiate = FALSE, conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95)`
Error in match.call() : ... used in a situation where it does not exist # how to correct this?
In addition: Warning message:
In get.dfcom(object, dfcom) : Infinite sample size assumed. # again, this warning don't occur with my original data
```

Any tip?

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting different answers (and not `NaN` values). From `sessionInfo()`, I have `broom.mixed_0.2.8 miceadds_3.11-6   mice_3.14.0       robustlmm_2.4-5  
lme4_1.1-27.1     Matrix_1.3-4      data.table_1.14.2` ...

Comment: I've updated R and packages and now I get all the information in `summary()`. The estimates are also different from those posted before (surely my mistake with set.seed). For example, now I get  `-0.0248`  for `(Intercept)` . Thank you @BenBolker

Comment: OK, if my answer solves your problem then you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load the `broom.mixed` package, which has tidiers for `rlmerMod` objects.  (The development version of `broom.mixed` has a `get_methods()` function:

```r
remotes::install_github("bbolker/broom.mixed")
library(broom.mixed)
print(get_methods(), n = Inf)
```

```
# A tibble: 22 × 4
   class     tidy  glance augment
   <chr>     <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl>  
 1 allFit    TRUE  TRUE   FALSE  
 2 brmsfit   TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   
 3 gamlss    TRUE  TRUE   FALSE  
 4 gamm4     TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   
 5 glmmadmb  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   
 6 glmmTMB   TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   
 7 gls       TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   
 8 lme       TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   
 9 lmList4   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  
10 mcmc      TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  
11 mcmc.list TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  
12 MCMCglmm  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  
13 merMod    TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   
14 MixMod    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  
15 ranef.mer FALSE FALSE  TRUE   
16 rjags     TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  
17 rlmerMod  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  
18 stanfit   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  
19 stanreg   TRUE  TRUE   FALSE  
20 TMB       TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  
21 varComb   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  
22 varFunc   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker! It works indeed, but `summary(pool.fit,conf.int = TRUE)` returns `NaN` for df, p.values and confidence intervals. Do I need to add more parameters to the function?

Comment: I'll check .....